# Access reports and Dashboard to Customer Community

Tags: customer-community

I am having some problem when i am accessing reports and Dashboard for Customer Community user. I am having two user one is having System Admin Profile and Other user having Community User.

So how can i give access to Reports and Dashboards to Customer Community profile?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: enable the the Chatter tab for them.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have already enabled chatter tab but it is not working